# jQuery version issues using twittr bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using jQuery 1.1.4 with my code. Now i want to use bootstrap to add some functionality to my code which uses jquery1.10.1 . So if i include latest version of jQuery.. there is some error in my previous jQuery script which was working fine initially.  how to resolve this issue with jQuery version?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What exactly is the error. There are lots of differences between 1.1.4 and 1.10.1, including several methods that are deprecated and several that are no longer supported.

Comment: [jQuery 1.1.4](http://blog.jquery.com/2007/08/24/jquery-114-faster-more-tests-ready-for-12/)?  Are you sure you typed that right?  If you did, that's from August 2007!  That's ancient.

Comment: What is the error you see?  Telling us there's an error isn't very helpful.  Can you show us the *exact* error message?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noConflict/ (the last example)

Comment: I was using an another jquery.hotkeys.js file which it could not find. Error was "undefined jquery.hotkeys.js". 
Kevin B thanks.. jquery.no conflict has resolved the issue. I basically wanted to know is this the only way we can do it.